# Picker onValueChange not being called on every selection

Tags: react-native

I have a picker with some hard coded values. On value change I want to update my redux store with the selected value using an action creator function from my store. I am running into an issue however where the onValueChange listener does not appear to be called for every selection change.

Picker code

```
<Picker selectedValue={this.props.settings.colorScheme} 
  onValueChange={(value, itemIndex) => this.props.onValueChange({prop: 'colorScheme', value})}>
  <Picker.Item value="blue" label="Blue"/>
  <Picker.Item value="green" label="Green"/>
  <Picker.Item value="orange" label="Orange"/>
  <Picker.Item value="purple" label="Purple"/>
  <Picker.Item value="red" label="Red"/>
</Picker>
```

Method passed into component to handle value change. I set breakpoints here but they only trigger typically for every other selection. Start on blue, then choose orange it fires. Then choose green and it doesn't fire, but then choose red and it will fire again.

```
handleValueChange({prop, value}) {
    this.props.updateSettings({prop, value})
}
```

Here is my redux action creator

```
export function updateSettings ({prop, value}) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_SETTINGS,
    payload: ({ prop, value }),
  }
}
```

My render method (where onValueChange becomes handleValueChange)

```
render() {
  return (
    <Settings
    settings={this.props.settings}
    onValueChange={this.handleValueChange.bind(this)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: FYI https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15556

Answer (score 1):

I have found the folowing workaround using `componentDidUpdate`:

```
export default class PickerComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {value:this.props.eventId}
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.props.eventId !== this.state.value) {
      this.props.chooseEvent(this.state.value)
    }
  }

  onValueChange = value => {
    if (value) this.setState({value})
  }

  makePickerItem (label, key) {
    const props = {label, key, value:key}
    return <Picker.Item {...props} />
  }

  makePickerItems = function * () {
    for (let id in this.props.things) {
      yield this.makePickerItem(this.props.things[id].name, eventId)
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.value}
        onValueChange={this.onValueChange}
      >
        {[...this.makePickerItems()]}
      </Picker>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's currently still an issue in the Picker component. Today someone proposed a simpler workaround that may be intersting to update your answer in the github related issue (I saw you commented there): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15556#issuecomment-360181487

Comment: In my case `onValueChange` was not called with my function that was passed down from the parent. That is why I worked around it in this way. But thank you for linking, it may be useful for someone else.